# Why isn't my jQuery method for getting iframe content height working in firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, iframe

I have the following code to resize an iframe based on it's contents height after the contents load:

```
$(frameID).load(function() {
    $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("body").height());
});
```

This works great in all browsers except for firefox.  In firefox, the height just gets set to 0.  Does anyone know why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem in moz, using the DOM ready method worked for me a while back!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(frameID).load(function() {
    $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("body").height());
  });
});
```